# Como instalar Imagick en php?

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer correr un codigo que no es mio, y me sale el siguiente error:

> ImagickExtensionNotFoundException: Imagick extension is not loaded.

Buscando un poco encontré el código de la excepción:

```
if (!extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    throw new Exception\ImagickExtensionNotFoundException('Imagick extension is not loaded.');
}
```

Ahora investigue un poco, y averigüe que dicha extensión no viene instalada con `php`, y encontre este lugar para su instalacion -->> http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php.

> El problema radica en que no entiendo como debo de instalarlo en `windows 10`.

Comment: Como instalaste el PHP en el Windows 10? descargaste un instalador de [php.net](http://php.net/) o usas un instalador como XAMPP?

Comment: @Jaime, lo instale con XAMPP

Comment: Hay unas [instrucciones en inglés](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/349/how-to-install-and-enable-the-imagick-extension-in-xampp-for-windows). Debes descargar e instalar el ImageMagick, luego descargar e instalar el módulo PECL para PHP correspondiente y modificar el archivo `php.ini`.

Comment: @Jaime, gracias lo veo, lo leo y te aviso como me va vale.

Comment: @Jaime, por mas que intento no encuentro compatibilidad con `php 7.1`, ahora estoy en proceso de bajar la version de php.

Comment: En los comentarios de la [documentación de imagemagick](http://php.net/manual/es/imagick.requirements.php) mencionan que han encontrado algunos problemas de compatibilidad con algunas versiones de ImageMagick. Al parecer, instalan el módulo PECL usando el ImageMagick en el [PECL/deps](https://windows.php.net/downloads/PECL/deps/)